# How to handle multiple clients asynchronously , on a web socket using python?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, bottle, gevent

I'm basically building a visual trace route application. The trace route is basically done using a python code and the results are send to the HTML page in real time using web socket. I basically need to do long polling( the server receives one request, process it and sent a maximum of 30 replies to each client at regular or irregular intervals), as well as handle multiple clients. I basically manipulated the below code to work for my application. I found the code from [Asynchronous Bottle Framework](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html)

```
from bottle import request, Bottle, abort
app = Bottle()
@app.route('/websocket')
def handle_websocket():
 wsock = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
 if not wsock:
  abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')

 while True:
  try:
   message = wsock.receive()
   wsock.send("Your message was: %r" % message)
  except WebSocketError:
   break

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketHandler, WebSocketError
server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 8080), app,
                handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

It does work on a single request. When I issue the second one.. 'wsock.send()' fails... it shows socket dead error. Could someone guide me on, how to handle multiple clients as well. Like, should I spawn a different process for each client ? What if a client requests trace for one domain, and again(before the full result is provided to him) requests for another. Thanks in advice

**Client side code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com:8080/websocket");
ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.send("Hello, world");
};
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    alert(evt.data);
};
```

Comment: What does the client-side code look like?

Comment: client side is basically a javascript code as provided in the same web page. http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html

Comment: But I do a lot of processing in the javascript, like working on a vector map... adding markers , drawing paths and so.... all these being carried out inside the ws.onmessage = function () { }

Comment: @XORcist : can you help me on this ?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your specific application, but [here is an minimal example application of abottle.py websocket server which does what I think you are asking for](https://github.com/7yl4r/mmogolpy/blob/master/app.py)